# Grammar matters - explanation of example

Tags: grammar, irony

I just stumbled over this from http://braythwayt.com/2015/05/04/grammar-matters.html :

> - "I'd like to thank the employees of FormerCo, who made me feel that my contribution mattered."
> - "I'd like to thank the employees of FormerCo who made me feel that my contribution mattered."
>
> One is a lovely tribute to a good company’s people. The other is a passive-aggressive criticism of a flawed company’s toxic culture.
>
> Grammar. Matters.

I am not an English native speaker and I do not get how that comma would discriminate a passive-aggressive tweet from a employee-praising tweet.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: It's just the usual thing of some uneducated native speakers thinking that punctuation has something to do with grammar. They like to embarrass themselves that way; it makes them feel they learned something at school.

Comment: Please summarise or quote from the article sufficiently so that the full question can be understood here without going to any other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a stretch, but I can see the point.

> I'd like to thank the employees of FormerCo, who made me feel that my contribution mattered.

With the comma, the second clause applies to all the employees of FormerCo, implying that they're all good people.

> I'd like to thank the employees of FormerCo who made me feel that my contribution mattered.

Without the comma, the second clause implies that only some of the employees of FormerCo had this effect and that most (or at least some) of them did not.